# Python Flask send_from_directory overwrites file on download

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to handle simple file uploads in Flask, and just stumbled onto a question. Anytime I download a file multiple times with `send_from_directory`, the file is overwritten each time, rather than saving an additional file.

This is what the function I'm using looks like, pretty much ripped straight from the documentation:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<name>')
def download_file(name):
    return send_from_directory(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], name, as_attachment=True)
```

It works well for what it is, when the function is called, the file is saved to the user's downloads folder. However, if there is a file of the same name already in the downloads folder, that file gets overwritten. The behavior I would have expected is if I download the file `foo.txt`, I would see `foo.txt` in my downloads folder. If I then download it again, I would still see the original `foo.txt`, as well as something like `foo.txt-2` in my downloads folder.

Is there anything I should be doing on the Flask side of things to achieve this behavior?

EDIT: It seems like this might actually be specific to Safari. I tried Firefox and it names the files sequentially as expected. So I guess my next question, is there a way to enforce this behavior on Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the behaviour you described you can do something like below

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/uploads/<name>')
def download_file(name):
    folder_path = app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]
    base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(name)
    
    counter = 1
    while os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder_path, name)):
        name = f"{base_name}-{counter}{extension}"
        counter += 1
    
    return send_from_directory(folder_path, name, as_attachment=True)
```

the above code checks if a file with the same name already exists in the downloads folder. If it does, it appends a counter to the base name of the file and increments it until it finds a unique name. This way, each downloaded file will have a unique name and won't overwrite existing files in the downloads folder.